# psycopg2 error when running datacube -v system init

Tags: open-data-cube

I followed the instructions from [here](https://opendatacube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/database/setup.html).

```
Open Data Cube core, version 1.8.6 
Ubuntu 16.04 
SQLAlchemy 1.4.27
```

After installation tried initialisation of database:

> $ datacube -v system init

This command is getting failed with following error:

```
2021-11-26 16:32:19,396 18775 datacube INFO Running datacube command: /home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/bin/datacube -v system init
Initialising database...
2021-11-26 16:32:19,698 18775 datacube.drivers.postgres._core INFO Ensuring user roles.
2021-11-26 16:32:19,713 18775 datacube.drivers.postgres._core INFO Creating schema.
2021-11-26 16:32:19,714 18775 datacube.drivers.postgres._core INFO Creating tables.
2021-11-26 16:32:20,219 18775 datacube.drivers.postgres._core INFO Creating triggers.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 719, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "not"
LINE 2: alter table agdc.metadata_type add column if not exists upda...
^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/bin/datacube", line 10, in
sys.exit(cli())
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/ui/click.py", line 200, in new_func
return f(parsed_config, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/ui/click.py", line 232, in with_index
return f(index, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/scripts/system.py", line 51, in database_init
was_created = index.init_db(with_default_types=default_types,
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/index/index.py", line 64, in init_db
is_new = self._db.init(with_permissions=with_permissions)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/drivers/postgres/_connections.py", line 201, in init
is_new = _core.ensure_db(self._engine, with_permissions=with_permissions)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/drivers/postgres/_core.py", line 112, in ensure_db
install_timestamp_trigger(c)
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datacube/drivers/postgres/_core.py", line 53, in install_timestamp_trigger
connection.execute(UPDATE_COLUMN_MIGRATE_SQL_TEMPLATE.format(schema=SCHEMA_NAME, table=name))
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1274, in execute
return self._exec_driver_sql(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1578, in _exec_driver_sql
ret = self._execute_context(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1845, in _execute_context
self.handle_dbapi_exception(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2026, in handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise
raise exception
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/home/user/anaconda2/envs/odc_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 719, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "not"
LINE 2: alter table agdc.metadata_type add column if not exists upda...
^

[SQL:
alter table agdc.metadata_type add column if not exists updated
timestamptz default null;
]
```

Some issues at github had the same problem but were moreover solved by downgrading SQLAlchemy to 1.2 but not in my case.

Comment: Good job reporting the bug: https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/issues/1209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Postgres 9.5, as the `add column if not exists` feature was added in Postgres 9.6 (in 2016) (which was datacube's previous minimum supported version).

Our minimum requirement [is Postgres 10 now](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core#system), which is also the minimum version still supported by Postgres themselves.